# power query - filter by all when the param is empty

Tags: dynamic, filter, powerquery

In Excel, Power Query, i want to filter my data to bring all when there is nothing mentioned in parameter table (which shall bring all data) but it does not work...

any suggestions ?

```
    project = if param {1} [Value] ="" then  "*" else param {1} [Value],
    "Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Project] = project ))
```

now query a bit changed , now i have 3 conditions

```
let

    param = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Secim"]}[Content],

    malzeme = if param {0} [Description] = "" then "*" else param {0} [Description],
    proje = if param {1} [Value] ="" then  "*" else param {1} [Value],
    firma = if param {2} [Value] ="" then  "*" else param {2} [Value],

    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([CODE] = firma ) and ([Project] = proje ) and ([Material Code] = malzeme ))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to either change the condition or not do any filtering at all. Something like this should work:

`"Filtered Rows" = if project = "" then #"Changed Type" else Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Project] = project)`

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. i have such 3 conditions for 3 different columns.

Comment: what i can do , is for each filter i can replicate the (reference back-to-back) and apply the filter in 3 parts but refreshing will be very slow...

Answer (score 1):

i solved the question with below query :

starts with :

---

```
param = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Secim"]}[Content],


    malzeme = param {0} [Value],
    proje = param {1} [Value],
    firma = param {2} [Value],
```

---

and ends with :

---

```
 #"Filtered Rows" = if proje = null then #"Changed Type" else Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Project] = proje),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = if malzeme = null then #"Filtered Rows" else Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [Material Code] = malzeme),
    #"Filtered Rows2" = if firma = null then #"Filtered Rows1" else Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each [CODE] = firma)


   in
    #"Filtered Rows2"
```